# SwiftUI navigationBarItem showing in strange position after showing a different bigger item

Tags: swiftui, navigationbar, navigationview

I have a simple split view that looks roughly like this:

```
NavigationView {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            self.selectedView = 1
        }) {
            Text("First")
        }

        Button(action: {
            self.selectedView = 2
        }) {
            Text("Second")
        }
    }

    Group {
        if selectedView == 1 {
            Text("View")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Text("Hi"))
        } else {
            Text("View")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Rectangle().frame(width: 150))
        }
    }
}
```

Now the navigation bar item `Hi` initially shows in the correct position (very far left). However, when I switched to the second view, which presents a really long rectangle in the navigation bar, and switch back to the original view, the `Hi` text is now shown in where the middle of the rectangle used to be (see picture).

[image: Screenshot]

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It is known SwiftUI bug. File one more bug to Apple.

Comment: @Asperi ok, thanks. Just wanting to make sure I did nothing wrong. New bug report incoming...